# Prove f is measurable and integrable on A

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, integrable-systems

Let $A := \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3 : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ x, 0 ≤ z ≤ 1\}$ and $f : R^3 → R$ a
function defined by
$f(x, y, z) :=\begin {cases} \frac {sinx} x
,\; for\; x \ne 0,\\ 1 , \; for\;  x = 0\end {cases}$ .
Show that f is measurable and integrable on A

f is measurable if

1. It's domain is measurable
2. for any a belonging to R one of the following is satisfy

x|f(x)>a is measurable

$x|f(x)\geq a$ is measurable

x|f(x)<a is measurable

$x|f(x)\leq a$ is measurable

1. So the domain would be [0,1]? so it would be measurable
2. 

We let a be a real number, and B={x∈R:f(x)<a}. Write out the intervals $I_1=(0,1]$, $I_2=(0)$
$B_k=B\cap I_k$ for k∈{1,2}

B is the disjoint union of the $B_k$ subsets.

Then x is in $B_1\text {iff}\; x\in I_1\; and\; \frac{sinx} x<a,\; i.e.\; x\in(0,k\pi]\cap I_1$
Hence, $B_1=(o,k\pi]\cap I_1$ is a measurable set since it's the intersection of two intervals?

Now to $B_2 : x$ is in B2 iff x∈I2 and a=1
So B2=I2 if a=1 and B2=∅ if a≠1.
It's a measurable set in both cases.
B is measurable as a (finite) union of measurable sets.

Is this correct? I used an answer to a similar question as a template, but I am not sure if I applied it correctly.

Integrable:
f is integrable on A $x\in (0,1]$
t f is
(Riemann) integrable on [a, b] if the upper integral and lower integral of f on [a, b] are
equal; that is, $(U)\int^b_af = (L)\int^b_a f$.

I don't know how to apply it because I get that the integral is a sequence $(x-\frac{x^3} {3(3!)}+\frac{x^5} {5(5!)}-...)$
Not sure how to move on from here.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Domain isn't $[0, 1]$, it's $A$ (by definition). That $f$ doesn't depend on other variables doesn't change its domain.

For proving measurability and integrability I think it's simpler to first prove that $f$ is just continuous (well known fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, and outside of $x = 0$ it's just fraction of two continuous functions both of which are non-zero), and then refer to general result for continuous functions.

Also, given that you are asked about measurability, integrability probably means Lebesgue integrability, not Riemann.

Comment: I get that A is the domain, but if x is [0,1] y[0,x] z[0,1] won't that mean that the domain can be max from [0,1]?

Comment: And what do you mean about general result for continuous functions? How will that help to prove measurability and integrability? Sorry for asking maybe basic questions, but I really want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, I would like to ask, if you could explain step by step not only on this example, but similar situations how I can solve them every time.  Bc I feel like I have a lot of ideas, but no concrete template.

Comment: No, domain is $[0,1] \times [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$. It's subset of $\mathbb R^3$, not of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I mean there is theorem that any continuous function is measurable and (if domain is bounded) integrable. Any textbook that introduces Lebesgue integration should include that.

Comment: So it is enough to prove that a function is continuous?

Comment: Yes, if you already have the theorem that continuous functions are integrable.